# RAD Studio Connections Profile Manage Option Not Visible

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am just starting out using Rad Studio and Delphi and I am trying to setup my iOS connection profile.

However, when I navigate to Tools ==>> Option ==>> Environmental Options ==>> Connection Profile Manager there is no Connection Profile Manager in Options list.

I am using RAD Studio 10.1 Starter edition.

[image: RAD Options Sreen - No Connection Manager Option ???]

Comment: What SKU are you using? You're missing the Provisioning item as well, which makes me think you're using a very low SKU (Professional has them). Are you using Starter or a trial version?

Comment: Starter, Version which one should i be using ???? I am totally new to this software platform only came across it yesterday

Comment: There's a [feature matrix (PDF)](https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/rad-studio-berlin-feature-matrix.pdf) that lists what is available in the different editions. It shows that there is no support for OSX, iOS, Android or Win64 in Starter - it does Win32 only. If you want to do most stuff that's not run-of-the mill (like XPlatform development), you're going to need a version higher than Starter, which is (as it's name suggests) just for getting  you started.

Comment: thanks yes i have noticed that matrix since my last message, are they higher versions available as a trial download ??? i have tried to download what i thought was the highest version for X platform but the options list is still the same as above

Answer (score 0):

Delphi Starter version only supports developing 32-bit Windows applications.

[Delphi Product Editions](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions)

Connection Profile Manager is used for running and debugging 64-bit Windows (when on a 32-bit Windows development PC), OS X or iOS applications. Since those platforms are not available in Starter edition, there is no need for having Connection Profile Manager in Options.